# Regex which works in Oracle is not working in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have regex with replace function which is working in SQL with Oracle:
`regexp_replace(product_name, '\s+\-.*', '')`

but it is not working in Spark SQL - looks, like matching is not working:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(product_name, '\\s+\\((-.*)\\)', '')`

How can I properly write it to get same results? In SQL with oracle I've replaced searched strings by '', but in Spark SQL nothing happened

I've tried to find regex by regexp_extract in Spark SQL - and I've got nulls

UPDATE: I've almost solved issue by using:  ' \ -.*'. The problem is still when I have white spaces around my string - how can I take only string?

Comment: `'\\s+-.*'` should work.

Comment: I've tried - still not working in same way like in Oracle. E.g in oracle I have 'ADVANCE®  - AAA' as product name, after regex I have 'ADVANCE®'. In spark SQL before and after regex still same product name  I see that there is parameter '1' after regex execution in spark sql, maybe shall I define it in some way? (regexp_replace(product_name, s+-.*, , 1))

Comment: Is there a space or a kind of a Unicode hard/soft space? Try `'(?U)\\s+-.*'`

Comment: There can be white spaces. Your new solution is not working as well...

Comment: Then it is not the regex pattern that is to blame.

Comment: Why is it working properly in Oracle then? And how to properly implement it in Saprk SQL ?

Comment: Could it be a character translation issue? Maybe the regex and data in Oracle matches the encoding but in new regex the character encoding is different?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with:  \ -.* works like expected finally - thanks all!